# How to find the nearest location which has sunny forecast

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks, weather-and-climate

Here is a scenario, I live in Seattle which is mostly cloudy or rainy these days. And I want to spend next weekend at a location, which should be close to my city but has reasonable probability of sunshine. I have found websites which give me forecast for a given location for next 10 days; but that requires me to keep trying the locations around me one by one, while increasing the diameter. I also found websites which show me the forecast for the whole state but only for next 1 or 2 days. So that is not very useful.

Comment: The accuracy of forecasts 10 days in advance isn't really there yet.  So the best you can do is look at cloud cover the dynamics and prevalent winds.

Comment: I wish we could put bounties on questions! I needed this on the turn of 2011/2012 when I had a three month client onsite in London and the lack of sunshine drove me near insane. I escaped for a weekend to Portugal as I had no better idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sunspot - Find Good Weather in Your Area
https://appsto.re/us/1ohaib.i

I made this app to address the problem. I'm also from Seattle. This does pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Seems this has been removed from the App Store?

Comment: Hi there, version 2 is out now: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1526413001

We removed V1 in 2018 due to problems with Yahoo Weather API. But the new version uses our own API that grabs weather data from NOAA directly

Answer (score 4):

[Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson) is correct.  The next best thing to do is look at historical data, if you have copious amounts of free time, to see locations weather history around you.

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a predictive weather map. For example, http://www.weather-forecast.com lets you get a map centred around any country or (for some countries) a state/province, fast forward to a date (up to 10 days), then look for sun.

For example, here's their [map centred around Washington State for next Saturday](http://www.weather-forecast.com/maps/Washington?hr=138) as an example. Each of those icons gives you a basic local forecast when mouseovered:

[image]

How reliable is it? Depends on the local weather data, but it's the simplest way I've found to browse for nearby sunshine.

The website's navigation is a bit... old-school. Start at http://www.weather-forecast.com/maps then find a country of interest, then hit the `+` button to choose a state/province then press the `→` arrow or drag the slider to navigate to the date and time you want.

---

Of course, how useful the information shown on the map is will vary by region...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Where2go from Meteoblue, they have very accurate forecast predictions as well
https://www.meteoblue.com/en/weather/outdoorsports/where2go

Comment: This appears to be what is known as a "link only" answer, meaning it is sometimes better left as a comment rather than an answer. You would have to earn enough rep to write comments, and to earn that rep you would need to write a high-quality question or answer somewhere, or to make a sufficiently large number of high-quality edits.

Comment: @user1271772 while this answer certainly could be improved the nature of the question does require links, some more details on features would be nice but it's fine. This is not the sort of link only answer where the information should be copied here.